# Angular1: Factory.method is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have an angular factory in coffeescript like so :

```
angular.module('app').factory 'appFactory', ['$q', 'Api', 'Flash', ($q, Api, Flash) ->

    obj = undefined

    get = ->
        if angular.isDefined(obj)
            return $q.when(obj)

        Api.AppInitializer.query().$promise.then ((response) ->
            obj = response
            return obj
        )
    { 
        get: get()
    }
]
```

And I'm calling it from a controller like so:

```
angular.module('app').controller 'appCtrl', ($scope, appFactory) ->

  appFactory.get.then ((data) ->
    $scope.obj = data
    )
```

Basically I'm fetching data from a factory, and if the data is currently undefined I'll make an Api request to fetch the data. This works as intended.

---

Now I need to pass a token params into the factory to fetch a specific record:

```
angular.module('app').factory 'appFactory', ['$q', 'Api', 'Flash', ($q, Api, Flash) ->
    obj = undefined

    get = (token) ->
        if angular.isDefined(obj)
            return $q.when(obj)

        Api.AppInitializer.get(token: token).$promise.then ((response) ->
            obj = response
            return obj
        )
    { 
        get: get()
    }
]
```

And I'm calling it from a controller like so:

```
angular.module('app').controller 'appCtrl', ($scope, appFactory) ->

  token = $scope.current_user.token_id

  appFactory.get(token).then ((data) ->
    $scope.obj = data
    )
```

Now I'm getting the error

> TypeError: appFactory.get is not a function

How do I pass the token parameter to appFactory.get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to return promise of `Api.AppInitializer` method when data exists.

**Code**

```
get = (token) ->
    if angular.isDefined(obj)
        return $q.when(obj)
    //return promise so that you can put .then inside controller.
    return Api.AppInitializer.get(token: token).$promise.then ((response) ->
        obj = response
        return obj
    )
//return factory object as well
return { 
    get: get //assign reference of get method here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, change get: get() to get: get without the brackets worked.

Comment: @Ryan.lay I also have the same thing in my answer

Comment: Yes, that's why I accepted your answer =).

Do you think Charlie's answer is a better way to write this function? I'm not at all familiar with how $q works

Comment: @Ryan.lay we both have same structure of code.. but he has missed caching logic.. Its upto you to decide which answer is better. But I always respect his answer's personally

Answer (score 1):

Several problems.

1. You are invoking `get()` in factory when you assign it to the 
   returned object
2. You only return promise if obj is undefined

You can store the request promise and return that without needing to use `$q`

```
angular.module('app').factory 'appFactory', ['$q', 'Api', 'Flash', ($q, Api, Flash) ->
    promise = undefined

    get = (token) ->
        if !angular.isDefined(obj)
         promise = Api.AppInitializer.get(token: token).$promise

        return promise
    { 
        get: get
    }
]
```

I don't use coffee so syntax may be off a bit

Comment: Thanks Charlie, your code worked right out the gate, but Pankaj answered first so I'll have to accept his answer. And thank you for correcting my code, I've gotten rid of the extraneous $q.

Comment: @PankajParkar yes, obj is used to cache the data between controllers